# How can I select specific regions from a shapefile?

Tags: r, mapping, shapefile

I have the present shapefile

```
heitaly<- readOGR("ProvCM01012017/ProvCM01012017_WGS84.shp")

FinalData<- merge(italy, HT, by.x="COD_PROV", by.y="Domain")
```

But I'm interesting not on all Italy, but also same provinces. How can I get them?

Comment: What does the rest of your data look like? If you go head(FinalData) or dput(FinalData) and paste the results into your question. This will help us answer you!

Comment: If you're familiar with dplyr and the tidyverse as a whole, then you can use the sf package which uses generic dplyr functions such as filter and select  to get the regions you want

Comment: maybe reversing your ```merge``` helps? I.e. ```merge(HT, italy, etc...)```.  But that is hard to see without knowing the structure of your data

Comment: see `all`, `all.x` and `all.y` in the documentation of the `merge` function, by default merge performs inner join so only data that are both in `italy`` and in `HT` will remain.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to select a category into a shapefile. I don't know for what do you want. For example if it is to colour a specific region in a plot or to select a row from shapefile attribute table.

To plot:

`plot(shape, col = shape$column_name == "element") # general example`

`plot(heitaly, col = heitaly$COD_PROV == "name of province") # your shapefile`

To attribute table:

`df <- shape %>% data.frame`
This will give you the complete attribute table

`row <- shape %>% data.frame %>% slice(1)`

This will give you the first row with all columns. If you change the number 1 to another number, for example 3, will give you the information for row number 3

I hope have been useful

Comment: I have to select multiple regions to color while the others have to remain white. How can I do that?

Comment: @plonthe You can make a previous vector called _cols_ and subset the provinces that you want plot.  For example `cols <- heitaly$COD_PROV[1:5]`. Then you can use the code `plot(heitaly, col = cols)`.